# Check if two sentences contain any matching word using Python

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying to simply check whether two sentences have any similar words.

Here's an example:

```
string_one = "Author: James Oliver"
string_two = "James Oliver has written this beautiful article which says...."
```

In this case, these two sentences match the criteria as they contain some common words.

I've tried a bunch of solutions and none seems to work properly. The two sentences would have a fairly large amount of words so splitting them into lists and finding the intersection would be really inefficient I think.

Comment: Is it inefficient? You should never assume things are inefficient till you have tried them and found that it is indeed a significant performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

We could convert the two strings into sets, and then check the intersection:

```py
s1 = "Author: James Oliver"
s2 = "James Oliver has written this beautiful article which says...."
w1 = re.findall(r'\w+', s1)
w2 = re.findall(r'\w+', s2)
intersection = set(w1) & set(w2)

if len(intersection) > 0:
    print("Found common words: " + ' '.join(intersection))
else:
    print("No words in commmon")
```

This prints:

```
Found common words: James Oliver
```

Your current suggested approach is fine, and finding all words in each sentence will take some time.

Comment: The question explicitly states that they knew this but thought it might be too inefficient

Comment: looks like `if intersection` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if they contain "any" and you don't care about which ones or how many, you can use `any`. With the combination of both of these, the program will stop execution once it finds a word in common without 1) calculating the rest of the words (and storing them in a list) and 2) iterating over the unused words.

```py
import re

s1 = "Author: James Oliver"
s2 = "James Oliver has written this beautiful article which says...."
words1 = set(re.findall(r'\w+', s1))
words2 = re.finditer(r'\w+', s2) # finditer evaluates lazily

if any(word2.group() in words1 for word2 in words2):
    print("Found words in common")
else:
    print("No words in common")
```